# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread is catched when I try set surfaceview in center of FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-framelayout

I have an activity which creates my custom SurfaceView for camera previewing in center of FrameLayout. In xml I have a FrameLayout with button and ImageView. When I click on button, I want ImageView shows over SurfaceView in center of FrameLayout. So when I run application I catch warning:

```
Skipped XX frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.rcd.perfecto.ui.CameraActivity">

    <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/fl_camera_preview"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
             android:id="@+id/iv_avatar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:visibility="gone"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <Button
             android:id="@+id/btn_photo_capture"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/btn_photo_capture"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>
   </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my custom SurfaceView

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Path mClipPath;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private WeakReference<FrameLayout> mFrameLayoutWeakReference;
    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    public CameraView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera, FrameLayout layout) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mFrameLayoutWeakReference = new WeakReference<FrameLayout>(layout);
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        init(context);
    }

    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
}

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
}

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        float radius;
        FrameLayout layout = mFrameLayoutWeakReference.get();
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0 || display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
            radius = layout.getWidth() / 2;
        } else {
            radius = layout.getHeight() / 2;
        }
        mClipPath = new Path();
        mClipPath.addCircle(layout.getWidth() / 2, layout.getHeight() / 2, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipPath(mClipPath);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        Display display = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
           parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);
           mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        }
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);
        }
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        }
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

And my activity:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.btn_photo_capture) Button mPhotoCaptureButton;
    @Bind(R.id.fl_camera_preview) FrameLayout mCameraPreviewFrameLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.iv_avatar) CircleImageView mAvatarImageView;

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraView mCameraView;


    public CameraActivity() {
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_photo_capture)
    void takePicture() {
        if (mAvatarImageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mAvatarImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mAvatarImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        if (checkCameraHardware()) {
            if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1) {
                mCamera = getCameraInstance(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            } else mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        }
        ViewTreeObserver observer = mCameraPreviewFrameLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mCameraView = new CameraView(CameraActivity.this, mCamera, mCameraPreviewFrameLayout);
                mCameraPreviewFrameLayout.addView(mCameraView, 0);
           }
        });

    }

    private static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;
   }

   private static Camera getCameraInstance(int id) {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;
    }

    private boolean checkCameraHardware() {
       return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    }

}
```

So my question is how can I avoid warning above or is there another way to set surfaceview in center of FrameLayout programmatically?